# SAP BO - Avoiding PROMPT in case of presence of a context

Tags: business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I am new to BO and want to understand the below scenario.

I have three columns.1) Year 2) Region 3) Amount

Region has three values--> A,B and C. Here C is total of A and B.

In the universe , I have 3 contexts defined: 1) Year and Region-A ,   2) Year and Region-B,                3) Year and Region-C

**Case1:**
Now in Webi, when I drag Year and respective regions along with the amount metric, the report will show the amount of the respective regions based on the context defined in the universe.

Ex 1: Year-2019 , Region- A , Amount-50

Ex 2: Year-2019 , Region- B , Amount-100

Ex 3: Year-2019 , Region- C , Amount-150(Sum of Region A and Region B)

**Case2**
Now when I drag the YEAR and AMOUNT , the amount gets doubled because it groups by all the regions leading to duplication.

Ex : Year- 2019 , Amount-300

So, in order to avoid the duplication I am including a PROMPT in the AMOUNT measure which will ask to enter the REGION value

So,in **Case1** ,because of the PROMPT, the context will come into play and also the PROMPT will appear in Webi. 
I wanted to understand, is there a way to avoid the PROMPT when the attributes are pulled as per Case1 because the context is also already working out there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the SQL of both statements if this is yet oustanding.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit weird formulated, but if I understand it correctly you have 1 webi report in which you have 2 tables one with region,year and value and 1 with only year and value. And you want to add a prompt only on the second table so it doesn't group it?

If this is the case you don't need a prompt, because you can't use a prompt on one table, what you need is an input control on your second table because input controls can be set specific for separate elements of a report. You can set the input control on region for your second table.